# How to get text labels to show in polygons from a topojson file?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, topojson

I am working on a map built with Leaflet and have a topoJSON file that is a featureCollection of country boundaries that make up Europe and other areas of the world. The feature collection contains attribute names of each country.

Question: What's the recommended way to get a country's name centered for each country's polygon? Should I use leaflet's tooltip function? I am using [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210608/show-text-inside-polygon-in-leaflet-map) as a starting point, but can't get my text labels to show. Any ideas? I have a topojson file with attributes that I am trying to pull from.

**[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/kjLjhbe1/)**

```
var earth = L.geoJson();
earth.bindTooltip('text label', {
    permanent: true,
    direction: 'center'
});


var naturalEarth = omnivore.topojson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dosstx/dcd1b4ebe3892527b12759226a21b900/raw/81abff4d455dbabe800c56aa7736dd4cbbfd1f64/topo.json', null, earth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind a tooltip to each layer using Leaflet omnivore, use the [Leaflet's `eachLayer` function](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup-eachlayer) to iterate over all layers in the topojson, after it's ready.

E.g.

```
var naturalEarth = omnivore.topojson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dosstx/dcd1b4ebe3892527b12759226a21b900/raw/81abff4d455dbabe800c56aa7736dd4cbbfd1f64/topo.json', null, earth)
  .on('ready', function() {
      naturalEarth.eachLayer(function(layer) { 
          //console.log(layer); //to inspect what properties are available
          layer.bindTooltip(layer.feature.properties.FORMAL_EN, {
              permanent: true
          });
      });
  });
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjLjhbe1/8/